# Как пройтись по нескольким файлам и вытащить из них определенную инфу на PHP?

Tags: php, циклы, simple-html-dom

Суть такая: есть 10 000 файлов с расширением html.
Нужно зайти в каждый и найти информацию, заключенную в уникальный тег. Допустим div с каким-нибудь id. 
Уже всю голову себе сломал. Подключил simple html dom и через find-> смог вытащить то, что мне нужно. Но я не могу сделать так, чтобы этот find проходился не по одному документу, а по всем по очереди. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

закидываете все фалы в одну папку и сканируете ее, получаете названия и циклом проходитесь по всем файлам

```
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files = scandir($dir);
```

Comment: Я так и сделал, но не получается пройтись циклом по файлам.

Comment: ну так кидайте тогда пример как вы делаете, я не телепат )

Comment: $arr = array();
for ($i = 2; $i < 5; $i++) {
// поиск по ключевому слову 
$fileName = file_get_contents("index-$i.html");
$fileName = preg_split("~\\n(?=\\s+)~", $fileName);
$word = 'id=....';
print_r(preg_grep("~$word~ui", $fileName));
}
$arr[] = $fileName;

Comment: В php совсем новичок, так что не ругайтесь за правильность и логику кода)

Comment: я не очень понимаю что вы этой регуляркой пытаетесь найти

Comment: ваш вопрос состоял в том что вы не понимаете как пройти по всем фалам по очереди

Comment: Я сейчас попробую так, как вы написали сначала. Извините что все столь нелогично :)

Comment: Вот смотрите. Я сделал как вы выше написали, вывел список, файлы получены. Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => index-2.html [3] => index-3.html [4] => index-4.html )
И вот моя проблема: как зайти в каждый из них и найти что-то? Это у меня и не получается

Comment: ну так же как вы и писали выше (file_get_contents) получаете контент, а дальше как хотите, или регуляркой или через DOM

Comment: Понял как сделать, возникла следующая ошибка: file_get_contents(..): failed to open stream: Permission denied in...
Не знаете как это убрать? Ищу в интернете, пока не могу найти. Как понял, дело в правах доступа. Но я работаю сейчас на open server, поэтому ответа пока не нашел

Comment: нет прав на чтение, не знаю какая у вас операционнай система 
гугл в помощь "дать права на чтения всем файлам в папке"